# App crash on launch Apple reject

Tags: ios, launch, crash

I have test and submit my app to Apple Store but Apple reject and response my app crash on launch. I have test my app on many model iPhone and iPad it's working normal, Have anyone can tell me why?
Crash log Apple send to me:

```
"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 11.2.5 (15D60)","incident_id":"F2C32C7F-63B2-4D96-8D90-1AF644DC5179","name":""}

Incident Identifier: F2C32C7F-63B2-4D96-8D90-1AF644DC5179
CrashReporter Key:   31ed20e652158d2a96b6662d50b1000ce2837b82
Hardware Model:      iPad5,1
Device Model:        J96AP
Process:             gamebaionline [5995]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/872913FE-A768-4837-81EB-F76C427CFBED/gamebaionline.app/gamebaionline

Version:             0 (2.0.5)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd.development [1]



Date/Time:           2018-03-03 07:05:30.9221 -0800
Launch Time:         2018-03-03 07:05:23.9926 -0800
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.2.5 (15D60)
Baseband Version:    n/a
UDID:                3ab61350a5372c6a81b3d6b6ac3e5a8c7d1cd04c
Report Version:      104
```

> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
>   Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
>   Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>   Triggered by Thread:  11
>   Application Specific Information:
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection  was mutated while being enumerated.'
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   abort() called.

Now i can't test with iOS 11.2.5 because Apple not allow signing in iOS version 11.2.5 or downgrade version to 11.2.5. Please help me.

Comment: You need to [symbolicate the crash report](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html) to determine where the crash occurred.  It is unlikely that this is caused by 11.2.5, but why can't you test with 11.2.5?  Have you tested using TestFlight?

Answer (score 1):

> Collection was mutated while being enumerated.

This mean that you have some data structure (like dictionary or array) and you iterate over elements and in same moment modify this structure, for example remove some elements. I suppose you to check all iteration that you do on very start. Or use symbolic breakpoint to find it. Note, that such crash can be a little bit tricky, because i guess some operation like remove or so may be not performed. Because of this you may or may not have crash on start

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine by doing the following,
1. Symbolicate the error logs received from Apple.
2. Delete the app completely from you actual device and run a build from Xcode on it, this time it will crash and show you the lines where the bugs are!!!